# Selection sort using max

Tags: prolog

I am trying to implement a custom version of selection sort, by selecting the maximum of the unsorted part and placing it at the end of the output (sorted) list.
I have a problem with the list recursive build. How can I start building the output list from the right?

```
sel_sort2([], []).
sel_sort2(L, R) :-
    max_list(L, M),
    delete1(M, L, L1),
    append(R, [M], R),
    sel_sort2(L1, R).
```

Comment: This goal looks suspicious: `append(R, [M], R)`...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `append` (which as pointed in the first comment is fishy). Instead you can write the second clause like:

```
sel_sort2(L, [E|T]) :-
    min(L, E),
    del(L, E, L1),
    sel_sort2(L1, T).
```

Where `min` takes the minimum element from the input list, and this element is on the first position in the result list, L1 is all elements from L without the first occurrence of a given element.